# is cron job what should be used in this case?

Tags: php, email, yii, cron

**Here is the 'use case':**

Admin goes to the newsletter.php, fills in the form for email, i.e the subject, group of users to whom email is sent, writes the message and clicks the "Send" button.

**Problem:**

The number of emails sent per hour should be limited to, let's say, 400. That is, one email should be sent approx. every 10 seconds. Besides, sent and not sent emails should be tracked.

**Question:**

1. Will cron job do the trick?
2. The code is written in Yii framework. Is it possible that cron job will be activated when the user clicks on the "Send" button or only in the command line?
3. If cron job can do things above, can it be activated only in specific action of specific controller? or it affects the whole script?

*Thank you*

Comment: 1- Yes it is a cron job. 2- You can do it in Yii refer to ***[ConsoleCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleCommand)***. Don not know much do you know about cron but make a script using consolecomamnd which runs every 10 secs, gets a singe email address in the queue and sends email to that address + removes it from the queue. 3- Yes in an action just build a queue (hint: mysql table) with the email address you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the concept of a cron job wrong.

Think of the process this way:

Admin presses the send button.

...That script creates a queue i.e. adds email address's etc to a database table lets call it Queue. And finishes.

You setup a cron job to run every 5 minutes for example.

...The cron starts a PHP script which processes X entries from the Queue table, sends those emails, removes the entries from the queue table, and stops.

...The cron job starts again automatically after 5 minutes and repeats the process...

All you have to do is work out how many emails to send in each execution of the cron job, and how often to run it, so you dont exceed your limits or get flagged as a spammer.

Comment: Yes, I am new to the concept of cron jobs. Thank you very much...Now I think I got the whole idea of how to accomplish the task at hand.

Answer (score 1):

***1-*** Yes it is a cron job.

***2-*** You can do it in Yii refer to ***[ConsoleCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CConsoleCommand)***. Don not know how much do you know about cron? but make a script using consolecomamnd which runs every 10 secs, gets a singe email address in the queue and sends email to that address + removes it from the queue.

***3-*** Yes in an action just build a queue (hint: mysql table) with the email address you need

Comment: Thank you sir...now I have some understanding of cron jobs)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that if you wanted to use cron to do such a thing, you would want your newsletter.php to write out a file to disk or database which contains the list of users. You would write a simple PHP script which would be triggered by cron which would be responsible for calling sendmail to send the messages. As each recipient is mailed you script would remove them from the list.

Alternately, you might want to look into some basic mailing list software. These often support a notion of throttled message sending.

I assume you are trying to manage limits imposed by your hosting provider related to number of emails sent per hour (antispam controls)

Answer (score 0):

Yes cron jobs can be used in such a scenario. I personally have developed newletter systems which use such methodology. However, I send 350 and do a cron job every hour.

You should check if there are any emails to be sent on the first line and leave the cron job running every hour. There is no need to activate the cron job when the send button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

`cron` itself just runs programs on a schedule. It doesn't have any logic in it that can know whether somebody clicked on a button, or logic that can know how many emails you've sent this hour, or which emails have or have not been sent.

`cron` runs under the control of a daemon. Although you *probably* could enable and disable it through a controller, you *probably* don't want to do that. If you're using `cron`, you usually need it to run all the time.

Instead, put the logic and the constraints into the program that `cron` runs.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use system or exec function you could call cron job or any thing else in terminal can do it

for example system("ps aux | grep crond");